# Is there a way to have iCloud back up only the latest photos?

Tags: ios, photos

I have only 50GB on iCloud but 256GB on my iPhone. I'd like to have iCloud to hold only the latest photos. So when I take new pictures/videos, the older ones would get removed from iCloud to make room for the new ones. What is the easiest way to do this? I am open to using 3rd party apps. Thanks.

Comment: iCloud [Photos] cannot do this without also removing the files from your phone.

Comment: This is exactly what [My Photo Stream](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201317) was great at and I'm sad it's [been shut down](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT210705). Feel free to leave feedback to Apple.

Comment: What other devices do you have? Mac, Windows PC, etc.

Comment: I have a couple of Macs.